# Symbol's function definition is void: insert-string

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, osx, functions, error-handling

```
;; Specify the startup banner. Default value is `official', it displays
;; the official spacemacs logo. An integer value is the index of text
;; banner, `random' chooses a random text banner in `core/banners'
;; directory. A string value must be a path to an image format  supported
;; by your Emacs build.
;; If the value is nil then no banner is displayed. (default 'official)
dotspacemacs-startup-banner 'random
```

When I set `dotspacemacs-startup-banner` to `'random` in my dot file, I got the following warning message when executing `emacs --debug-init`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function insert-string)
  (insert-string (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert-file-contents file) (let ((banner-width 0)) (while (not ...) (let ... ...) (forward-line 1)) (goto-char 0) (let (...) (while ... ... ...))) (buffer-string)) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))))
  spacemacs-buffer/insert-ascii-banner-centered("/Users/sunqingyao/.emacs.d/core/banners/000-banner.txt")
  (if (image-type-available-p (intern (file-name-extension banner))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-image-banner banner) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-ascii-banner-centered banner))
  (progn (spacemacs-buffer/message (format "Banner: %s" banner)) (if (image-type-available-p (intern (file-name-extension banner))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-image-banner banner) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-ascii-banner-centered banner)) (spacemacs-buffer//inject-version))
  (if banner (progn (spacemacs-buffer/message (format "Banner: %s" banner)) (if (image-type-available-p (intern (file-name-extension banner))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-image-banner banner) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-ascii-banner-centered banner)) (spacemacs-buffer//inject-version)))
  (progn (if banner (progn (spacemacs-buffer/message (format "Banner: %s" banner)) (if (image-type-available-p (intern (file-name-extension banner))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-image-banner banner) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-ascii-banner-centered banner)) (spacemacs-buffer//inject-version))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-buttons) (spacemacs//redisplay))
  (let ((banner (spacemacs-buffer//choose-banner)) (buffer-read-only nil)) (progn (if banner (progn (spacemacs-buffer/message (format "Banner: %s" banner)) (if (image-type-available-p (intern (file-name-extension banner))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-image-banner banner) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-ascii-banner-centered banner)) (spacemacs-buffer//inject-version))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-buttons) (spacemacs//redisplay)))
  spacemacs-buffer/insert-banner-and-buttons()
  (save-excursion (if (> (buffer-size) 0) (progn (set (quote save-line) (line-number-at-pos)) (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (erase-buffer)))) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line "") (setq spacemacs-buffer--note-widgets nil) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-banner-and-buttons) (if (and (boundp (quote spacemacs-initialized)) spacemacs-initialized) (progn (configuration-layer/display-summary emacs-start-time) (if dotspacemacs-startup-lists (progn (spacemacs-buffer/insert-startupify-lists))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-footer) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line spacemacs--default-mode-line) (force-mode-line-update) (spacemacs-buffer-mode)) (add-hook (quote emacs-startup-hook) (quote spacemacs-buffer//startup-hook) t)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create spacemacs-buffer-name)) (page-break-lines-mode) (save-excursion (if (> (buffer-size) 0) (progn (set (quote save-line) (line-number-at-pos)) (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (erase-buffer)))) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line "") (setq spacemacs-buffer--note-widgets nil) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-banner-and-buttons) (if (and (boundp (quote spacemacs-initialized)) spacemacs-initialized) (progn (configuration-layer/display-summary emacs-start-time) (if dotspacemacs-startup-lists (progn (spacemacs-buffer/insert-startupify-lists))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-footer) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line spacemacs--default-mode-line) (force-mode-line-update) (spacemacs-buffer-mode)) (add-hook (quote emacs-startup-hook) (quote spacemacs-buffer//startup-hook) t))))
  (progn (setq spacemacs-buffer--banner-length (window-width) spacemacs-buffer--last-width spacemacs-buffer--banner-length) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create spacemacs-buffer-name)) (page-break-lines-mode) (save-excursion (if (> (buffer-size) 0) (progn (set (quote save-line) (line-number-at-pos)) (let ((inhibit-read-only t)) (erase-buffer)))) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line "") (setq spacemacs-buffer--note-widgets nil) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-banner-and-buttons) (if (and (boundp (quote spacemacs-initialized)) spacemacs-initialized) (progn (configuration-layer/display-summary emacs-start-time) (if dotspacemacs-startup-lists (progn (spacemacs-buffer/insert-startupify-lists))) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-footer) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line spacemacs--default-mode-line) (force-mode-line-update) (spacemacs-buffer-mode)) (add-hook (quote emacs-startup-hook) (quote spacemacs-buffer//startup-hook) t)))) (if save-line (progn (goto-char (point-min)) (forward-line (1- save-line)) (forward-to-indentation 0)) (spacemacs-buffer/goto-link-line)) (switch-to-buffer spacemacs-buffer-name) (spacemacs//redisplay))
  (if (or (not (eq spacemacs-buffer--last-width (window-width))) (not buffer-exists) refresh) (progn (setq spacemacs-buffer--banner-length (window-width) spacemacs-buffer--last-width spacemacs-buffer--banner-length) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create spacemacs-buffer-name)) (page-break-lines-mode) (save-excursion (if (> (buffer-size) 0) (progn (set (quote save-line) (line-number-at-pos)) (let (...) (erase-buffer)))) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line "") (setq spacemacs-buffer--note-widgets nil) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-banner-and-buttons) (if (and (boundp (quote spacemacs-initialized)) spacemacs-initialized) (progn (configuration-layer/display-summary emacs-start-time) (if dotspacemacs-startup-lists (progn ...)) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-footer) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line spacemacs--default-mode-line) (force-mode-line-update) (spacemacs-buffer-mode)) (add-hook (quote emacs-startup-hook) (quote spacemacs-buffer//startup-hook) t)))) (if save-line (progn (goto-char (point-min)) (forward-line (1- save-line)) (forward-to-indentation 0)) (spacemacs-buffer/goto-link-line)) (switch-to-buffer spacemacs-buffer-name) (spacemacs//redisplay)))
  (let ((buffer-exists (buffer-live-p (get-buffer spacemacs-buffer-name))) (save-line nil)) (if (or (not (eq spacemacs-buffer--last-width (window-width))) (not buffer-exists) refresh) (progn (setq spacemacs-buffer--banner-length (window-width) spacemacs-buffer--last-width spacemacs-buffer--banner-length) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create spacemacs-buffer-name)) (page-break-lines-mode) (save-excursion (if (> (buffer-size) 0) (progn (set ... ...) (let ... ...))) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line "") (setq spacemacs-buffer--note-widgets nil) (spacemacs-buffer/insert-banner-and-buttons) (if (and (boundp ...) spacemacs-initialized) (progn (configuration-layer/display-summary emacs-start-time) (if dotspacemacs-startup-lists ...) (spacemacs-buffer//insert-footer) (spacemacs-buffer/set-mode-line spacemacs--default-mode-line) (force-mode-line-update) (spacemacs-buffer-mode)) (add-hook (quote emacs-startup-hook) (quote spacemacs-buffer//startup-hook) t)))) (if save-line (progn (goto-char (point-min)) (forward-line (1- save-line)) (forward-to-indentation 0)) (spacemacs-buffer/goto-link-line)) (switch-to-buffer spacemacs-buffer-name) (spacemacs//redisplay))))
  spacemacs-buffer/goto-buffer()
  spacemacs/init()
  (if (not (version<= spacemacs-emacs-min-version emacs-version)) (message (concat "Your version of Emacs (%s) is too old. " "Spacemacs requires Emacs version %s or above.") emacs-version spacemacs-emacs-min-version) (load-file (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name) "core/core-load-paths.el")) (require (quote core-spacemacs)) (spacemacs/init) (spacemacs/maybe-install-dotfile) (configuration-layer/sync) (spacemacs-buffer/display-info-box) (spacemacs/setup-startup-hook) (require (quote server)) (if (server-running-p) nil (server-start)))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/sunqingyao/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1302
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sunqingyao/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/sunqingyao/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/sunqingyao/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266   \306=\203\307\310Q\202? \311=\204\307\312Q\202?\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202?\313\307\314\317#\203>\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d\210\203\247\332!\333\232\203\247\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201\211\202\214\336!\203\213\202\214\314\262\203\245\337\"\203\243\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/7676). This problem should be fixed in the next release.

**Quick fix:**

Change the function `insert-string` to `insert` in `~/.emacs.d/core/core-spacemacs-buffer.el`, and everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

Other packages besides just spacemacs may use `insert-string`. A more general fix is to add to your `.emacs` file:

`(or (fboundp 'insert-string) (defalias 'insert-string 'insert))`

Comment: `insert-string` had been marked as obsolete for many years before that report.  Of course, there might still be packages using it (tho it's been a while since I heard any mention of it, so it must be limited to very obscure packages), but the better general fix is to adjust the packages to use `insert` instead of `insert-string`, like @nalzok suggests.